# Is it possible to add custom property to an Openlayers VectorLayer and later access it when a feature is selected?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to add a custom property to my Vector Layers when initializing the layers because the source doesn't have all the data I need.

If I understood the API docs right, it should be possible, but I don't know how to return the value of the custom property when selecting a feature on the VectorLayer on a map.

I'm initializing the VectorLayer with following code:

```
const someVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    url: "https://example.com/api/v1/foobar",
  }),
  customProperty: 'foobar'
});
```

And I'm trying to access that property to set my fetch url to get stuff from the right place when the feature is clicked:

```
function onSelect(e) {
  const featureValues = e.target.getFeatures().getArray()[0];
  const featureId = featureValues.get('id');
  const featureCustomProperty = featureValues.get("customProperty");
  const fetchUrl = `https://example.com/api/v1/${featureCustomProperty}/${featureId}`;

  fetch(fetchUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
}
```

I appreciate any help I can get on the subject. Obviously I'm not an Openlayers expert yet. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loader` to setProperties before add Features to the map.

```
var vectorSource = new Vector({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = '***'
    fetch(url).then(data => {
        // format data to features , this step depends on your actual situation
        const features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(data)
        features.forEach((feature, index) => {
            // add a custom properties to feature
            feature.setProperties({
                index
            })
        });
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features)
    })
  },
  strategy: bbox,
})
```

```
function onSelect(e) {
  '''
  const props = selectedFeature.getProperties()

  '''
}
```

Comment: This seems to help in my case, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong variable to access your custom property property.

*selectedFeatureValues* should be *someVectorLayer*